# How can I repopulate my dropdown on a front-end form?

Tags: registration, validation

I am allowing guest registrations - everything is working fine. I am hung up on getting my drop down menu to repopulate/hold its value if there are any errors while submitting.

I have a `states` field in the CP which is a dropdown.

Within my twig template I have this:

```
{#
 # Get all of the states.
 #
 #}
 {% set states = craft.fields.getFieldByHandle('states').getFieldType.options %}
 {% if states|length %}
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="state">State</label>
         <select id="state" name="fields[address][state]" class="form-control">
             <option value="">Select</option>
             {% for option in states %}
                 <option val="{{ option.value }}"
                     {%- if account is defined and option.value in account.address.state %} selected {% endif -%}>
                     {{ option.label }}
                 </option>
             {% endfor %}
         </select>
     </div>
 {% endif %}
 {% if account is defined %}
     {{ errorList(account.getErrors('state')) }}
 {% endif %}
```

I am using SmartMap to capture my address hence the name of `fields[address][state]`.

Just doing this:

```
{%- if account is defined %} selected {% endif -%}
```

Gets the last option selected, so I know `account` is getting defined, its something in my `and` part.

All of my data is getting captured correctly, I just can't see past the obvious here I guess.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to @carlcs I found that the value of my `state` field was getting saved as the label. I'm not sure if thats a function of SmartMap, or something else I might have done.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
...
<option value="">Select</option>
{% for option in states %}
    <option val="{{ option.value }}"
        {%- if account is defined and option.label in account.address.state %} selected {% endif -%}>
        {{ option.label }}
    </option>
{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, here is how I was able to repopulate a "normal" drop-down (not address/SmartMap):

```
...
<option value="">Select</option>
{% for option in myField %}
    <option val="{{ option.value }}"
    {%- if account is defined and option.label in account.myField.label %} selected {% endif -%}>
       {{ option.label }}
    </option>
{% endfor %}
```

I think it's also worth noting that by setting `myField` as a required field in the CP, I needed to hard-code the `<option value="">Select</option>` in the template rather than putting it as a field value. When I had it as a field value, I (think) Craft was accepting that as a selected value and I was not getting the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `dump` the `account` variable to see why the conditional doesn't work as you're expecting. I don't really see the reason to why you'd need the `in` containment test, but I'd just use `dump` for debugging.

Comment: `dump` was the answer. The system was saving the `label` as the actual field value. I've updated my question for anyone else. Not sure if it's a SmartMap thing? TBD...